# StackOverflowError при попытке создать бин javax.sql.DataSource

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

Пытаюсь использовать JDBCTemplate. Полный код проекта [по ссылке](https://github.com/SkillsUpCourses/SpringHomeWork/blob/JDBCTemplate%2BMongoDB/SpringJavaConfig/src/main/java/com/stoxa/springjavaconfig/DAO/ContactJDBCDao.java)

в конфигурациях создаю бины

```
@Bean
DataSource dataSource() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource =  new DriverManagerDataSource();
    /**Properties property = new Properties();
    FileInputStream propertyFile = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/mydb.properties");
    property.load(propertyFile);*/
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb");
    dataSource.setUsername("Ksu");
    dataSource.setPassword("KurochkaRyaba13");
   // dataSource.setConnectionProperties(property);
    return dataSource();
}

@Bean
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() throws IOException {
    return new JdbcTemplate((javax.sql.DataSource) dataSource());
}
```

При попытке скомпиллировать зацикливается подключение JDBC драйвера.
Cначала в логах пишет долго

```
 Dec 17, 2015 5:02:23 AM         org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
 INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Потом ошибка

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in com.stoxa.springjavaconfig.Config.AppConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.activation.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
    at com.stoxa.springjavaconfig.TestClass.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:24)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.activation.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getContextClassLoaderInternal(LogFactory.java:808)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getFactory(LogFactory.java:419)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDataSource.<init>(AbstractDataSource.java:42)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.<init>(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:34)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.<init>(DriverManagerDataSource.java:71)
    at com.stoxa.springjavaconfig.Config.AppConfig.dataSource(AppConfig.java:89)
    at com.stoxa.springjavaconfig.Config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$943c5217.CGLIB$dataSource$5(<generated>)
    at com.stoxa.springjavaconfig.Config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$943c5217$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6405c777.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:318)
    at com.stoxa.springjavaconfig.Config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$943c5217.dataSource(<generated>)
    at com.stoxa.springjavaconfig.Config.AppConfig.dataSource(AppConfig.java:95)
    at com.stoxa.springjavaconfig.Config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$943c5217.CGLIB$dataSource$5(<generated>)
    at com.stoxa.springjavaconfig.Config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$943c5217$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6405c777.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:318)
    at com.stoxa.springjavaconfig.Config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$943c5217.dataSource(<generated>)
    at com.stoxa.springjavaconfig.Config.AppConfig.dataSource(AppConfig.java:95)
    at com.stoxa.springjavaconfig.Config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$943c5217.CGLIB$dataSource$5(<generated>)
    at com.stoxa.springjavaconfig.Config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$943c5217$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6405c777.invoke(<generated>)
```

Answer (score 8):

У вас бесконечная рекурсия

```
@Bean
DataSource dataSource() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

 ...

    return dataSource();
}
```

Возможно, стоит вернуть не метод, а `dataSource`.

Comment: да, спасибо, увидел

Comment: @stoxa, если вопрос решён, то нажмите на галочку слева от ответа.